# Showing current user details ( eg. name) - Bloc flutter

Tags: android, flutter, bloc

https://github.com/OdongoWaga/chill
This is the project i am trying to make changes.

---

How to show _currentUser.name that is current user name...it's just a code where used in a project.
If i am using this code just to show current user name (or details) then circular progress bar  comes up and i just want to simple show _currentUser.name , just a text name on a page.But failed to do so.

```
import 'package:dating1/bloc/search/bloc.dart';
import 'package:dating1/models/user.dart';
import 'package:dating1/repositories/searchRepository.dart';
import 'package:dating1/ui/widgets/iconWidget.dart';
import 'package:dating1/ui/widgets/profile.dart';
import 'package:dating1/ui/widgets/userGender.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';



class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userId;

  const Search({this.userId});

  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  final SearchRepository _searchRepository = SearchRepository();
  SearchBloc _searchBloc;
  User _user, _currentUser;
  int difference;

 

  getDifference(GeoPoint userLocation) async {
    Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();

    double location = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(userLocation.latitude,
        userLocation.longitude, position.latitude, position.longitude);

    difference = location.toInt();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _searchBloc = SearchBloc(searchRepository: _searchRepository);

    super.initState();
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return BlocBuilder<SearchBloc, SearchState>(
      bloc: _searchBloc,
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is InitialSearchState) {
          _searchBloc.add(
            LoadUserEvent(userId: widget.userId),
          );
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blueGrey),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (state is LoadingState) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blueGrey),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (state is LoadUserState) {
          _user = state.user;
          _currentUser = state.currentUser;

          getDifference(_user.location);
          if (_user.location == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "No One is Here...",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "wait we will add soon ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            );
          } else
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: profileWidget(
                padding: size.height * 0.05,
                photoHeight: size.height * 0.824,
                photoWidth: size.width * 0.95,
                photo: _user.photo,
                clipRadius: size.height * 0.02,
                containerHeight: size.height * 0.45,
                containerWidth: size.width * 0.9,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.02),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.06,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child:Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.red[500],
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                    child: Text("${_user.gender}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25.0),),
                                  )),
                              userGender(_user.gender),
                            ],
                          )
                          //Text("${_user.gender}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25.0),),
                          // userGender(_user.gender),

                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[

                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                " " +
                                    _user.name +
                                    ", " +
                                    (DateTime.now().year - _user.age.toDate().year)
                                        .toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: size.height * 0.05),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.location_on,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                difference != null
                                    ? (difference / 1000).floor().toString() +
                                        " km away"
                                    : "away",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
//                        iconWidget(EvaIcons.flash, () {}, size.height * 0.04,
//                            Colors.yellow),
                            iconWidget(Icons.clear, () {
                              _searchBloc
                                  .add(PassUserEvent(widget.userId, _user.uid));
                            }, size.height * 0.08, Colors.blue),
                            iconWidget(FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart, () {
                              _searchBloc.add(
                                SelectUserEvent(
                                    name: _currentUser.name,
                                    photoUrl: _currentUser.photo,
                                    currentUserId: widget.userId,
                                    selectedUserId: _user.uid),
                              );
                              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'You can chat when ${_user.name} likes you back \n ',timeInSecForIosWeb: 5);

//                          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'You can chat when ${_currentUser.name} likes you back \n ',timeInSecForIosWeb: 5);
                            }, size.height * 0.06, Colors.red),
//                        iconWidget(EvaIcons.options2, () {}, size.height * 0.04,
//                            Colors.white)
                          ],
                        ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0,),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
        } else
          return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be life saving to me and appreciable dear.

Comment: It's not clear what SearchBLoc does on the LoadUserEvent event? Maybe somehow it fails to load the user so it never outputs the LoadUserState?

Comment: one is user retrived from firebase and the current user is the person running the app

Comment: Add the BLoC code to your question. There is no way we are able to tell why the emitted event is `InitialSearchState` or `LoadingState` right now.

Comment: https://github.com/OdongoWaga/chill
Basically this is the whole project which i am trying to make it. you can find the code here.